# Calculating volume above each face of a triangular prism in a sphere

Tags: calculus, volume

I have been attempting to create a mathematically perfect 5 sided die, however the calculations seem to be where I end every time.

-I know this isn't physically possible, just looking for a mathematical one.

-I don't like the "pinwheel" die where they are simply pentagonal prisms.

-The other calculations I find do not line up with what I have found

The further I look into the probability of dice landing on certain sides, the more I see the idea of having the object in a sphere. The volume above each face is proportional to the probability of landing on that face. The idea of center of gravity only seems to work when all sides are of the same shape.